# Only variables should be passed by reference in session creating

Tags: php, session

i have a session class in which i'm trying to generate session id and storing it into database but it is giving an error that is Only variables should be passed by reference

Here is the Script Part->

```
private function newSid() {

        $this->sessionId=$this->generateString($this->sid_len);

        while ( $this->getSidCount($this->sessionId) > 0 || is_int($this->sessionId) ) {

                $this->sessionId=$this->generateString($this->sid_len);

        }

        $this->forcedExpire = time()+ $this->session_max_duration;
        $expireTime = time() + $this->session_duration;

        $this->SQLStatement_InsertSession->bindParam(':expires', $expireTime, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->SQLStatement_InsertSession->bindParam(':forcedExpires', $this->forcedExpire, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $this->SQLStatement_InsertSession->bindParam(':sid', $this->sessionId, PDO::PARAM_STR, $this->sid_len);
        $this->SQLStatement_InsertSession->bindParam(':ua', $this->getUa(), PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);

        return $this->SQLStatement_InsertSession->execute();

}
```

for more Detail visit to see full session class https://www.twekr.com/session.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, the issue is here:

```
$this->SQLStatement_InsertSession->bindParam(':ua', $this->getUa(), PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
```

Instead of that, try assigning `$this->getUa()` to a variable:

```
$ua = $this->getUa();
$this->SQLStatement_InsertSession->bindParam(':ua', $ua, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
```